# Directions in sequence diagram

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm a newbie en latex and Im trying to make some diagrams with *tikz*. I want to make the messages in one direction only, I think i'm  missing a parameter of `call` that could do the trick but I haven't found anything useful yet. I have the following diagram

[image]

```tex
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt,tikz]{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{pgf-umlsd}

\newcommand{\newthreadShift}[4][gray!30]{
  \newinst[#4]{#2}{#3}
  \stepcounter{threadnum}
  \node[below of=inst\theinstnum,node distance=0.8cm] (thread\thethreadnum) {};
  \tikzstyle{threadcolor\thethreadnum}=[fill=#1]
  \tikzstyle{instcolor#2}=[fill=#1]
}



\begin{document}
\begin{sequencediagram}
    \centering
    \newthread{A}{Alice}
    \newthreadShift{B}{Bob}{10cm}
    \begin{call}{A}{ $B_i = R_i^{3} \cdot f(x_i,y_i) (mod (n))$}{B}{}
    \end{call}

\end{sequencediagram}
\end{document}
```

How can I remove de dotted lines in order to make the `call` in one or another way and not both. Maybe there are easier ways to do this, I just want to make a visual representation. How can I achieve this? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Please complete your code with all packages and declarations. Where is a `sequencediagram` defined?

Comment: My bad, I forgot to add one line. It is defined in `pgf-umlsd` package.

Comment: I think you want `messcall` instead of `call`

Comment: Thank you yo much! @SandyG Indeed `mescall` solves my problem